# C# multi method attached to event, how to handle return value?

Tags: .net, events, c#-2.0

This is the call:

```
    bool isValid = true;
    if (this.ExternalConstraint != null)
    {
      isValid &= this.ExternalConstraint(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
    if (isValid)
    {
        //...
    }
```

The event look like:

```
public delegate bool externalConstraint(object sender, EventArgs args);
event externalConstraint ExternalConstraint;
```

When debugging I notice that all method attached to the event is called but only the last return seem to return to this line : `isValid &= this.ExternalConstraint(this, EventArgs.Empty);`. How can I get the event to return every method or to handle the all return value to take a decision?

Comment: Your delegate doesn't look like it's for an event (and `ExternalConstraint` is a horrible name for an event!), so why `(object sender, EventArgs args)` in the signature?

Comment: Give me your suggestion... Why it's a bad name... you can add External Constraint if required... and the signature is kind of the default one so I do not understand your point, can you explain?

Comment: `ExternalConstraint` doesn't sound like an event (think `OnClick` or `OnUserVomitsOnKeyboard`).

Comment: Ok, but isn't the IDE show clearly what is an event or not? I feel using "On" in front of the event name very old school, like using strMyMessage or iAge instead of MyMessage or Age... but it must be a personal taste ;)

Comment: Using meaningful names is different than using Hungarian notation. In particular, the prefix "On" isn't really part of Hungarian notation.

Comment: Using `On` prefix is not normal for .NET events. However, .NET event names describe, well, _events_ that happen - e.g. `Click`, `MouseMove`, `PropertyChanged`. `ExternalConstraint` does not fall into this scheme.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's considered bad practice to depend on return values when using events. Rather, you should use a user-defined `EventArgs` to get back results.

```
public class ConstraintEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}
```

It's also important to implement some mechanism in which multiple event listeners won't override each other's values. Most of the time (with a boolean flag), we will allow (or encourage) users to only explicitly turn it on (never off).

For example, with `CancelEventArgs` it's never a good idea to set it to `false` explicitly; Users should always set it to `true` or do nothing. The same idea should apply here with `IsValid`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`Delegate.GetInvocationList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist.aspx) on the delegate and process the return values individually.

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom EventArgs class with a method for add return code.  Each listener can then call the method, and after the event completes, you can iterate through the return codes.  This also allows you to add data about which listener returned what, or why.

```
private class MyEventArgs : EventArgs {
   public void addReturnCode(bool retCode){
       //...
   }

   public IList<bool> getReturnCodes(){
       //...
   }

}
```

Comment: Good suggestion, I guess it's the simplest solution. I'll take a look at .GetInvocationList too. Thank for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You would iterate on the result from ExternalConstraint.[GetInvocationList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.getinvocationlist.aspx) instead of just calling the Constraint delegate.